# How to find out which admin made a change in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-event-log

If a mailbox limit is set, is it possible to find out when and who made the change, by searching through event logs, is there an event ID specific to this that can be searched for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, the feature that you are looking for is called *[Administrator Audit Logging](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335052%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx)*:

> You can use administrator audit logging in Microsoft Exchange Server
>   2010 to record actions taken by a user or administrator that make
>   changes in your organization. By keeping a log of the changes, you can
>   trace a change to the person who made it. You can also augment your
>   change logs with detailed records of the change as it was implemented,
>   use the records to comply with regulatory requirements and requests
>   for discovery, and so on. By default, audit logging is enabled in new
>   installations of Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1).

Here is an excelent article explaining in detail how to use this feature:

[Exchange 2010 Administrator Logging walk-through](http://msexchangeguru.com/2012/09/10/admin-logging/)